# Importing data from worksheet into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I am trying to import data from MS Excel (Pro Plus 2013) to SQL Server 2014. Every time I attempt to do so I get the errors below. The columns in the the table are set to `nvarchar(50)` while in Excel none of the columns have more than 30 characters. I have tried recreating the Excel spreadsheet over and over again, just to be sure I am doing everything right. I just can't get the data to import.

These are the errors I receive:

> Validating (Error) Messages:
>
> - Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Agent_First_Name" with a length of 255 to database column "Agent_First_Name" with a length of 50.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Agent_Last_Name" with a length of 255 to database column "Agent_Last_Name" with a length of 50.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Agent_Email" with a length of 255 to database column "Agent_Email" with a length of 50.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Agent_Extension" with a length of 255 to database column "Agent_Extension" with a length of 4.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Agent_Cell_Phone" with a length of 255 to database column "Agent_Cell_Phone" with a length of 10.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "Agent_ID".(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - tableAgents" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: There may have been something about `mysql` that you left out of the original question that was actually important. I was asking for clarification.  Nothing more or less. There is an [edit] (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30020483/edit) link for just such cicumstanses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to import into an existing table.  I would recommend starting with importing the data into a new table (for example, "tmpAgent" -- and you can delete this table later).  Allow SQL Server to pick the tables size of the import, or you can set the size in the "Edit mappings" section of the import.

After you have imported the data into a new table, then create a query to move it into your Agent table.

Comment: You are a life saver. I wished I would have asked this question earlier today. I have spent HOURS going thru the forums and articles online. THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message.

Turns out I had a rogue cluster of merged cells in the excel file. I un-merged those cells, re-tried the import, and all my data were successfully imported to the excel file.